# Logging on Linux I get error message: Connection failed: connection refused. No more addresses to try

Tags: linux

I get error message when I logon my Linux server. The error message is: "Connection failed: connection refused. No more addresses to try.".

I am using the app Terminus. On my new laptop I am creating the same accounts which were made on my old laptop. On my old laptop I can login and also on my new one. But when I try again to login I get the already mentioned error message.

I have contacted the servicedesk of the provider (Vultr) and they say that I must check the configuration of the ssh (is not on port 22) to ensure that it is setup properly . But I have never had problems with my ssh before.

I hope that someone can and will help me with:

How to resolve the cause of the error message
How can I check the setup of the ssh?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct address to connect to the server?

Comment: Hello Tero, Yes I am sure, that I am using the correct address (port) to the server.
Have you any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: "Connection refused" means that there either is no process listening on the port, or there is a firewall blocking the connection. Or maybe your new laptop has some firewall doing this, but it is unlikely.

Comment: I have also tried to logon with my old laptop and I get the same error message. In the app, on the old laptop, is nothing changed. 
I have used "systemctl status sshd" to check the ssh. I have done this via a console viewer on the side of the hosting company. 
How can I check the firewall? And how can I see that the firewall is the problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you made any changes to server lately?

Comment: No nothing.

But I have had contact with the hosting company (Vultr) and they say that the SSH port is still not responding publicly at this time. 

And therefor I will have to check  listening service and firewall configurations.

How can I do this?

Comment: use the third party support which you pay for? I mean you should have a contract on support for the software and basically a debug is a part of most third party software

Comment: The third party support has solved the problem.
How / What I don't know.